# How does $n < 2^n$ become $\log n < n$ by taking log of both sides?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

How does $n < 2^n$ become $\log n < n$ by taking the log of both sides?

I understand the left side but I do not understand the right side of the inequality. The once was $\log 2^n$ becomes $n$ for some reason...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The logarithm function is an increasing function, which means it is valid to take the $\log$ of each side of the equation.

$$\log (n) \lt \log(2^n) \iff \log(n) < n\log 2$$

This is because one of the laws of exponents tells us $$\log a^b = b\log a.$$

If you are using $\log_2$, then $\log_2(n) < n\log_2(2) = n$

Comment: ...and $\log$ is increasing.

Comment: Also, sometimes (like in complexity analysis) multiplicative constants (like $\log 2$ here) are ignored.

Comment: is log always increasing by default or what hint tells me it is increasing? If the constant was not 2, but 100, do we just omit the constant all the time?

Comment: Have you tried graphing the $\log$ functuion? You'll see it is always increasing. A function is an increasing function means for  arbitrary real numbers $a, b$,$$a \lt b \implies f(a) = f(b) all \forall a, b \in \mathbb R$$

Comment: $\log_a$ is increasing if $a>1$ and decreasing if $0<a<1.$

Comment: Note that $1<2$ and $\log_{1/2}1=0>\log_{1/2}2=-1.$

Comment: @mfl: Yes...I didn't realize that you were referring to $a$ as a base, as in $\log_a$ which I now see you clearly defined. My bad.

Comment: Just a typo. It should read $\log(n)<n\log2$ in third line.

Comment: I fixed a minor typo for you, hope you don't mind.

Comment: Not at all, @CameronWilliams.  I was editing just as you were! ;-)

Comment: This answer and many of the comments seem to fail to understand the main point: Why is $\log(2^n)$ the same as $n\text{ ?}$ ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Yes, I address that @Michael: logarithm rule, and the fact that $\log_2(2) = 1$.

Comment: @amWhy : If by "the logarithm rule" you mean $\log(a^b)=b\log a$, then I'm not convinced that you've been very direct.  That is a derived rule, whereas here one should use the definition directly.

Comment: @MichaelHardy may you state the definition you are talking about?

Comment: The definition is that $\log_a b$ is the number $c$ for which $a^c=b$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 4):

$ n < 2^n $ then $\log n <n \log 2$, since $\log 2 < 1$, we claim that $$\log n < n$$

Comment: is log 2 < 1 true if the base was any arbitrary number?

Comment: No. Only if the basis is bigger than $2.$